# How do I write an endless loop that can be terminated by the user in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to write a program that runs one of three functions, depending on which button is pressed by the user. The third function should run in an endless loop until the user interrupts it somehow. However, I'm struggling to code this. I tried to write a while(System.in.available() == 0) loop, but when I press Enter while that part of the program is active, it simply does nothing. Here is the part of my code that I think is relevant:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            new WaspmoteSim();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String command = e.getActionCommand();

    if (command.equals("Demonstration Mode")) {
            DemoMethod();
    }
    if (command.equals("Distribution Fitting Mode")) {
            FittingMethod();
    }
    if (command.equals("Operational Mode")) {
            OperationsMethod();
    }
}

public void OperationsMethod() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process proc;
        while(System.in.available() == 0) {
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println(workingDir);
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /C C:\\Progra~1\\R\\R-3.2.1.\\bin\\Rscript.exe " + workingDir + "\\Fitter.r");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(8);
        }
    }
```

and the WaspmoteSim function's declaration is:

```
public class WaspmoteSim extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Using  Thread.interrupt(),interrupt the thread and inside your code keep checking whether the Thread has been interrupted or Thread.interrupted()